# How can I retrieve a variable of type int[num_elem] from a heap-allocated array of type int*?

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need to access iterators like end() and begin() on an array that I allocated on the heap as follows:

```
int* init_env_heap = new int[NUM_ELEM];
```

This has type `int*` and the iterators do not work immediately for it.

When I allocate it on the stack, however, the type is `int[NUM_ELEM]` and the iterators work:

```
int init_env_stack[NUM_ELEM] = { };
```

How can I use the iterators on the `init_env_heap` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing about iterators is that they emulate pointers. The beginning of a heap-allocated area is the pointer pointing to the first element. The end is the beginning plus the size.

It will be easy to remember is you just think of a couple of things:

- The "beginning iterator" is always a pointer to the first element
- The "end iterator" is always pointing to one beyond the last element
- For any valid pointer `p` and index `i` the expression `p + i` is equal to `&p[i]`.

In your case the first element is pointed to by `init_env_heap`, and a pointer to one beyond the last element is `&init_env_heap[NUM_ELEM]` which is equal to `init_env_heap + NUM_ELEM`.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the pointer arithmetic. It will be a pain to refactor my code though because there are enhanced for loops where the iterators are implicit. Those will have to be changed to systemcpro's for loops it seems like. That's why I was hoping for a conversion from int* to int[elem] (only one place in the code to change)

Answer (score 1):

Pointers conform to the concept of iterator already. For example,

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**){

    constexpr int SIZE = 5;
    int values[SIZE] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int* start = values;
    int* end = values + SIZE;
    for(int* iter = values; iter < end; ++iter)
        std::cout << "value: " << *iter << '\n';


}
```

Comment: They work in lambdas exactly the same way as normal iterators etc

Comment: Thanks for showing how to loop over the values. As I indicated in my comment to the other answer, I currently use enhanced for loops. I think I will have to change them to the for-loop format that you show here. It seems like there is no way to expose the usual int[size] type from the int* type I have available.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn - You don't have to refactor to heavily. Write a small utility that provides a "view" of the array, and has a `begin` and `end` members that return these pointers.